# Order is not syncing from shopify to my shopify-app

Tags: node.js, shopify-app

Order is not syncing from shopify to my shopify-app, when a customer place order without email address and  only provide mobile number. How can i resolve this problem, so my shopify-app recieve orders that are made with mobile numbers?

Answer (score 0):

You can use shopify webhooks, Webhooks are a useful tool for apps that want to execute code after a specific event occurs on a shop, for example, when customer create order from frontend then shopify will notify you via json/xml response if you create order/create webhook for merchant store. It does not depend on email or mobile number. You can manage order response according to your logic in your shopify-app.

How to create webhook for app :
https://help.shopify.com/en/api/reference/events/webhook